# How can i use pytorch model in C#?

Tags: python, c#, pytorch

I have a pytorch model in NLP and a script for use it in python. Now i want to use this script in C#. I tried run python script from C# and it worked. I get user sentence in C#, pass it to python and its outputs use in C#. The problem is that i want to do this work in a loop until user select exit but every time it goes to python code, it must load pytorch model and its time consuming.
Is there a way to load model one time and then in a loop get input from user and inference with loaded model?

Answer (score 3):

you can export the model in ONNX format and then use the [OpenCV DNN module](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d58/tutorial_table_of_content_dnn.html) or [tensorrt](https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt#:%7E:text=NVIDIA%C2%AE%20TensorRT%E2%84%A2%20is,high%2Dperformance%20deep%20learning%20inference.&text=TensorRT%20provides%20INT8%20and%20FP16,detection%2C%20and%20natural%20language%20processing.) for inference purposes. It will give you a significant boost in speed and your whole code will be in C#.

Comment: Exporting to ONNX and using ONNX Runtime also works. Here are some docs on how to use C# + ONNX Runtime: https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/get-started/with-csharp.html https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-csharp-cv-template